# Como fazer abrir uma caixa OpenFileDialog ao selecionar uma Tab do TabControl?

Tags: c#, winforms

Gostaria que quando o utilizador selecionasse uma Tab determinada, abrisse de imediato uma caixa de OpenFileDialog.

Já tenho essa SaveFileDialog, mas é no método click do botão:

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Ficheiros\";
        save.Title = "Salvar Ficheiro";
        save.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel) return;

        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter escritor;

            if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tpFicheiro)
            {
                escritor = new StreamWriter(save.FileName, false, Encoding.Default);
                escritor.WriteLine(tbFicheiro1.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                escritor = new StreamWriter(save.FileName, true, Encoding.Default);
                escritor.WriteLine(tbFicheiro2.Text);
            }

            escritor.Flush();
            escritor.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode sobrecarregar 2 evento do Controle `TabControl`:

- Selecting -> é disparado quando a página do `TabControl` está sendo selecionada.
- Selected -> é disparado após a seleção da página do `TabControl`.

Você pode encontrar os eventos através da aba Propriedades. Uma vez a `TabControl` selecionada, na aba propriedades click no ícone com imagem de raio na barra superior da aba. Localize a categoria ação e 2 clicks no evento correspondente a sua necessidade. Reescreva seu código no método de evento gerado pela IDE.

Outra forma é escrever seu próprio método:

```
private void SelecionandoPagina(object objeto, TabControlCancelEventArgs evento)
{
     //Aqui voçê escreve seu código...
}

private void PaginaSelecionada(object objeto, TabControlEventArgs evento)
{
    //Usei para teste.
     MessageBox.Show($"Pág:{evento.TabPageIndex.ToString()}, Nome:{evento.TabPage.Name}");
}
```

Se optar pela pela forma acima não esqueça de sobrecarregar o Controle:

```
tabControl1.Selecting += new TabControlCancelEventHandler(SelecionandoPagina);

tabControl1.Selected += new TabControlEventHandler(PaginaSelecionada);
```